# how to get all chrome download links with wget command tool automatically?

Tags: bash, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, wget

I'm trying to download all the images that appear on the page with WGET, it seems that eveything is fine but the command is actually downloading only the first 6 images, and no more. I can't figure out why.

The command i used:

`wget -nd -r -P . -A jpeg,jpg http://www.edpeers.com/2013/weddings/umbria wedding-photographer/`

It's downloading only the first 6 images relevant of the page and all other stuff that i don't need, look at the page, any idea why it's only getting the first 6 relevant images?

Thanks in advance.